# How do I setup RT so that anyone in a single domain (example.org) has 'create ticket' priviliges via email?

Tags: email, request-tracker

I have a small RT installation started that I'm using to simplify my life working with different groups of users, and presently I create all the tickets and add the person who's requesting them as a CC to each one.

I realized that I could simply have them email a 'ticket create' address because rt-mailgate can create a new ticket when it receives email.  This works brilliantly for myself, because my email address is in the RT system, but sue@example.org, say, can't email that address (tech@help.example.org) and get a ticket created.  The emails appear to be silently ignored if RT doesn't know about the user.  I could add each person's email by hand, but then if a new person is added at that site, they will not be able to submit tickets until I add their email.

Is there a kosher way to do this?  I have found plenty online about how to setup rt-mailgate and I have it working, and I can email back and forth with it all day.  If my users could as well, that will ease some of my pain considerably.

I do realize RT is overkill for a one-or-two man installation, but it is the best tool I've been able to find and I'm expecting to grow. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the RT_SiteConfig.pm coming with a default RT installation:

```
# If this is set to 1, then users should be autocreated by RT
# as internal users if they fail to authenticate from an
# external service.
Set($AutoCreateNonExternalUsers,    1);
```

This should also create internal users when a mail arrives form an unknown user. There should also be functionality available that auto-assigns new users a password and send it by mail, but I don't use this.

If you have another source for valid users in your system (like your LDAP database), you can also use this as auth source. RT will then create a user stub in its own database.